# Sum the results of a DateDiff

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 3 columns:  SessionRole (varchar(100)), Start Date (datetime2(7)) and End Date (datetime2(7)). I need to calculate a value that is the sum of End Time - Start Time for all sessions in the table.

The table looks like this:

```
SessionRole  StartDate                       EndDate
Admin        2021-02-24 22:21:27.5800000    2021-02-24 22:21:27.5800000
Supervisor       2021-02-25 13:56:40.8966667    2021-02-25 14:29:07.8866667
Admin        2021-02-25 14:29:20.8866667    2021-02-25 14:29:20.8866667
```

I was able to get the end time - start time values in this query:

```
Select SessionRole,CAST(COALESCE(DATEDIFF(second, StartDate, Isnull( EndDate,getdate())),0) AS decimal(16,4))/3600 AS TotalSessionTime
from dbo.Session
Group By SessionRole, StartDate, EndDate
```

This gives me an output that looks like this:

```
0.213055555
0.000000000
0.000000000
0.000000000
0.022500000
```

Now I need to sum those values.  I tried adding a sum to this datediff but can't get it to work.  Should this be an inner join with a query (I could not get that to work either).  Any direction would be great.

Here is what I tried with sum - just adding the sum in front of the whole datediff:

```
Select SessionRole,CAST(COALESCE(SUM(DATEDIFF(second, StartDate, Isnull( EndDate,getdate())),0)) AS decimal(16,4))/3600 AS TotalSessionTime
from dbo.Session
Group By SessionRole, StartDate, EndDate
```

I get the message:
The SUM function requires 1 argument(s).

Comment: *"I tried adding a sum to this datediff but can't get it to work."* Why didn't it work? What *was* that attempt?

Comment: Sum will work, show us what you tried?

Comment: Sorry, I figured I was way off base with the sum in the datediff.  I added what I tried now.  I just placed the entire datediff part in parenthesis with a sum in front

Comment: Aggregating and grouping on `StartDate` and `EndDate` makes no sense. If you are aggregating the value, why are you grouping on it?

Comment: I will eventually have many roles in the table so I want to pull out a sum of session time for each role.

Comment: I got it!  Thank you so much.  I was overwhelmed and thought I was way off.  I removed the Group By Start and End Date.  The sum in the location it was worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CTE :

```
WITH CTE (SessionRole,TotalSessionTime)  
AS (  
    Select SessionRole,CAST(COALESCE(DATEDIFF(second, StartDate, Isnull( EndDate,getdate())),0) AS decimal(16,4))/3600 AS TotalSessionTime
    from dbo.Session
    Group By SessionRole, StartDate, EndDate 
    )  
SELECT sum(TotalSessionTime) as sumofsessions  
FROM CTE
```

Comment: This worked too.  I will research the With and become more familiar and to learn which is better.  Thank you.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

I removed the Group By Start and End date and the sum worked.

```
Select SessionRole,CAST(COALESCE(SUM(DATEDIFF(second, StartDate, Isnull( EndDate,getdate()))),0) AS decimal(16,4))/3600 AS TotalSessionTime
from dbo.Session
Group By SessionRole
```